# How do I redirect back to my search results?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

I'm starting work on an MVC4 application. I have a controller named People. The index view has search functionality. When the user enters search criteria, the search results are displayed on a view named SearchIndex. This view was scaffolded using the default scaffolding. On the SearchIndex view, each person is listed with Edit, Details, and Delete links to the right of each row. When the clicks one of the links, the resulting view has a link at the bottom of the the page labeled "Back to List." When clicking the "Back to List" link, the user is taken back to the index view of the Patient controller with no search results, forcing the user to enter the search criteria again.

I'd like to modify the "Back to List" link so it redirects to the SearchIndex view with the previous search results so the user doesn't need to perform another search. How do I do this? I noticed the SearchIndex view has the search criteria in the querystring but I'm not sure how to pass the querystring around or if that's even the correct way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Its hard to follow your question, because you talk about views. It would be easier if you would explain what URLs you have and if  they accessed by get or post.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the entered search criteria into a viewmodel and then when you hit "back to list" you should pass the search results back to that page in the same way that you pass them in the first place to perform the search.

So, if you are using ActionLinks you can do something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "SearchIndex", "People", new { searchTerm = model.SearchTerm});
```